# Python read in JSON file with multiple values as a Dict

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to read in a JSON file as a dict. Below is an example of the JSON file it has multiple Keys which are the same but i cant seem to read it in as a dict. It keeps reading in as a list.

```
[{
    "success": true,
    "id": "",
      "q": " 24 hour care",
    },
    "result": {
        "search_metadata": {
          "created_at": "2021-02-10T13:08:52.370Z",
          "processed_at": "2021-02-10T13:08:54.440Z",
          "total_time_taken": 2.07,
        },
        "ads": [
            {
              "domain": "www.milestonehouse.com",
              "displayed_link": "www.milestonehouse.com/",
            }
        ],
        "related_searches": [
            {
              "query": "Google contact number",
              "link": "https://www.google.co.uk/",
              "block_position": 6
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "success": true,
    "id": "",
    "search": {
      "q": " 24 hour care",
    },
    "result": {
        "search_metadata": {
          "created_at": "2021-02-10T13:08:52.370Z",
          "processed_at": "2021-02-10T13:08:54.440Z",
          "total_time_taken": 2.07,
        },
        "ads": [
            {
              "domain": "www.milestonehouse.com",
              "displayed_link": "www.milestonehouse.com/",
            }
        ],
        "related_searches": [
            {
              "query": "Google contact number",
              "link": "https://www.google.co.uk/",
              "block_position": 6
            }
        ]
    }
}]
```

Is there a way i can read this in? Currently using:

```
with open('output.json') as SerpOutput:
    SerpRes = json.load(SerpOutput)
```

Comment: Well, the file is a list of json objects. Are you expecting a single `dict`?

Comment: thats what i was hoping for

Comment: What happens with the duplicate values? do they get overwritten? What should your dict look like?

Comment: it only has duplicate values in this example it doesn't in the real thing. I couldn't upload my document (over 4000 lines)

Comment: `json.load` can take a `object_pairs_hook` argument, which is a callable that can accept a list of key/value pairs rather than a `dict` for a JSON object. This callable can construct some thing other than a `dict` than can handle duplicate keys.

Comment: That said, I don't see any duplicate keys, just an array of objects that have the same keys. You'll get back a `list` of `dict`s back from `json.load`. (Though what you have posted seems to have a stray `},`, making it invalid JSON in the first place.)

Comment: This is not valid json. Full stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's reading it as a list because the file has a list. I'm not sure why you would expect it to be any different.

What you can do, since you say in the comments that the dictionaries in the list are not suppose to have duplicate keys, is to merge them all together into a single dictionary.

That could look something like:

```
from functools import reduce

def merge(a, b):
    a.update(b)
    return a

with open('output.json') as SerpOutput:
    res_list = json.load(SerpOutput)

result = reduce(merge, res_list)
```

This will basically take a list of dictionaries like:

```
[
    { 'a': 1 },
    { 'b': 2 }
]
```

And turn it into:

```
{
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2
}
```

Comment: would this work if there were more JSON object e.g 4/5 not just the 2 in the example?

Comment: yes, that's what the reduce function is going to do, it's going to go through all elements of the list and merge them together, resulting in a single dictionary in the end

Comment: so does it delete anything from it?

Answer (score 0):

```
SerpOutput.write(SerpRes)
```

This should write to the output file the variable which is a python dict

Comment: I dont understand what you mean?

Comment: You want to write a python dict to a file right?

Comment: well i want it to be a dict variable that i can call in my script

Comment: You can call SerpRes

Comment: that is a list though not a dict

Comment: Say you want to get the block_position you just have to type 
`SerpRes[0]["result"]["related_searches"]["block_position"]`

Comment: would there be no way to query all of the "result" in one go?

Comment: You would just have to loop over the answers

Comment: `for i in len(SerpRes): SerpRes[i]["result"]`

Comment: like for result in SerpRes?

Comment: yes i get what you mean. However, if i did for i in SerpRes: print(SerpRes[i]["result"]["related_searches"]["block_position"]) i get TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict

Comment: I have changed the code to check for the len() of the array that should work @Will

Answer (score 0):

Consider this JSON:

```
{"foo": 3, "foo": 5}
```

By default, `json.load` will overwrite the first key with the second:

```
>>> json.loads('{"foo": 3, "foo": 5}')
{'foo': 5}
```

You can specify a different callable that will accept a list of key/value pairs instead as the `object_pairs_hook` argument. For example:

```
def combodict(kvs):
    d = {}
    for k, v in kvs:
        d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
    return d
```

Then

```
>>> json.loads('{"foo": 3, "foo": 5}', object_pairs_hook=combodict)
{'foo': [3, 5]}
```